# Node standalone / self hosting services and inter service communications

Tags: node.js

I have experience with C# WebApi running self hosting services via Top-Shelf. These services communicate via RabbitMQ to the self hosting data layer services.

I think my question is an architecture question:

How would I do this in Node, on Windows or Linux ?

Do I have the Express/Node WebApi all started via a command line
e.g.

node WebApi1.js

node WebApi2.js

node WebApiN.js

And the node data services started via the command line 
e.g.

node dataService1.js

node dataService2.js

Would I communicate between the services with RabbitMQ or
should I implement a serviceBus that is embedded ( npm install ? ) in the Node services code itself ? What npm packages would you recommend ?

I'd like to decouple everything, so that it's a messaging system or as near to it.
Also, the WebApi services and Data layer services are on different servers and could be on different domains

Comment: My initial thought is to have stand alone node services communicating via RabbitMQ. This seems the correct solution having spent a day researching it. This is what I needed after chewing over several other solutions https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still something you are looking into, but I definitely think that utilizing RabbitMQ to facilitate communication between individual node services is a great pattern.

As a bonus to the "What npm packages would you recommend", we just released our OSS RabbitMQ driver for Node.js: BunnyBus (https://github.com/xogroup/bunnybus)